# Using a Join in a CAML query in an SRS Report

Tags: sharepoint-2010, reporting-services, caml

I created a SRS report which connects to a SharePoint list web service. I am able to get data from one list using this query

```
<Query>
  <Method Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" Name="GetListItems"/>
  <SoapAction>http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems</SoapAction>
</Query>
```

and two parameters called "listName" and "rowLimit".

Now, I want to use a [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535061.aspx) element in this query and connect two different list.

Is this possible in SRS reports using CAML queries? The Join element should show up as a child of the View element but I don't see how this can be used in a SRS report.

My understanding is that the datasets in SRS reports cannot do joins when the data source is a SharePoint list.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen a single CAML query that get data from two lists. By C# joins are possible but in CAML query it is not possible.

thanks

Yahiya Iqbal